# How to check a checkbox using Puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, google-chrome-devtools, puppeteer

I have used the code like this:

```
await page.$$eval( 'input[name=name_check]', checks => checks.forEach(c => c.checked = true)
```

But this is for multiple checkboxes. I want to use this for a single checkbox.

How can I check only one checkbox?

Comment: replace `$$eval` with `$eval` and checks will become only one element matching the selector

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### page.$eval()

You can use [`page.$eval()`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageevalselector-pagefunction-args-1) instead of [`page.$$eval()`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageevalselector-pagefunction-args) to check one checkbox instead of multiple checkboxes:

```
await page.$eval('input[name="name_check"]', check => check.checked = true);
```